# Updating a JSONObject without static name

Tags: java, json

I am trying to update a JSON Object but I found it a little complex.

My JSON Object looks like this:

```
  "TableName1.ID": 0,
  "TableName1.value": 0,
  "TableName1.value": 0,
  "TableName2.ID": 0,
  "TableName1.value": 0,
  "TableName1.value": 0,
  "TableName2.value": 0,
```

There will be different tables but there are some values with the same name.

What I am trying to do is update my JSONObject to look like this:

```
  "TableName1.ID": ChangedValue,
  "TableName1.value": 0,
  "TableName1.value": 0,
  "TableName2.ID": ChangedValue,
  "TableName1.value": 0,
  "TableName1.value": 0,
  "TableName2.value": 0,
```

My Code so far:

```
public static void getJsonValues(JSONArray inputAr) throws JSONException {
for(int i=0;i<inputAr.length();i++) {
    JSONObject jso= inputAr.getJSONObject(i);

    if(jso.toString().contains("ID")) {
        jso.put([This need to be the same as before(e.g. TableName1.Value)],"ChangedValue");
    }
    System.out.println(jso.toString());
}
```

}

If I fill `jso.put(jso.toString(),"ChangedValue")` it fills every json object of my array. Also is there another method to check the Object value instead of .contains?

Comment: You can use `org.json` to begin with. Also, care explaining your input object, looks like its an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do change the JSON easily using the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library. But for sure there are other libraries that allow you to do so.

Typically I create a [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) project with these dependencies - you could also use [Gradle](https://gradle.org/docs/) as well:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Then based on this file here:

```
{
  "TableName1.ID": 0,
  "TableName1.value1": 0,
  "TableName1.value2": 0,
  "TableName2.ID": 0,
  "TableName2.value1": 0,
  "TableName2.value2": 0,
  "TableName2.value": 0,
  "TableName3.ID": 0,
  "TableName3.value1": 0,
  "TableName3.value2": 0,
  "TableName3.value": 0
}
```

you can replace the ID's to for example this:

```
{
  "TableName1.ID" : "ffa7aa01-e399-4acc-bd8d-d078b327ec49",
  "TableName1.value1" : 0,
  "TableName1.value2" : 0,
  "TableName2.ID" : "4e416251-804d-4b2c-bdb3-a2ca7e7366ef",
  "TableName2.value1" : 0,
  "TableName2.value2" : 0,
  "TableName2.value" : 0,
  "TableName3.ID" : "1cf4900d-f5e6-4abe-810d-336e45313f62",
  "TableName3.value1" : 0,
  "TableName3.value2" : 0,
  "TableName3.value" : 0
}
```

using this code here (see the comments for what it does):

```
// read the file and make sure the input stream is closed after leaving the block.
try (InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("so_example.json")) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(in); // create a tree structure from the JSON
    jsonNode.fields().forEachRemaining(entry -> { // loop through the JSON fields and change only the values of the elements with a certain pattern
        if(entry.getKey().endsWith(".ID")) {
            entry.setValue(new TextNode(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        }
    });
    String res = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonNode); // convert the in memory structure to a pretty string
    System.out.println(res);
}
```